# Page numbers on bottom right footer

Tags: header-footer, titlesec

I'm using class report (one sided document) and the package titlesec. How can I put the page numbers on bottom right footer on all the pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{main}{\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{main}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{main}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```